# How to align SVG path or increase the size of the element?

Tags: css, svg

**Background:**

I am making an icon loader with two letters and an outer layer. I want to align them correctly

```html
<svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="-4 -4 120 150">
        <title>Loader Logo</title>
        <g>
          <path
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="5"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="M 50, 5
                      L 11, 27
                      L 11, 72
                      L 50, 95
                      L 89, 73
                      L 89, 28 z"
          />
          <path
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="5"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="M 45.2 0 L 54.9 0 L 32.7 70 L 22.2 70 L 0 0 L 9.8 0 L 27.5 58.3 L 45.2 0 Z"
          />
           <path
            transform="translate(65 0)"
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="5"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="M 0 70.001 L 0 0.001 L 18 0.001 A 35.716 35.716 0 0 1 24.843 0.616 Q 28.805 1.39 31.9 3.138 A 18.895 18.895 0 0 1 35.15 5.451 Q 41.012 10.645 41.286 20.428 A 34.665 34.665 0 0 1 41.3 21.401 Q 41.3 27.401 38.45 32.251 Q 35.6 37.101 30.5 39.901 L 44.5 70.001 L 33.7 70.001 L 21.2 42.601 Q 19.6 42.801 17.9 42.801 L 9.1 42.801 L 9.1 70.001 L 0 70.001 Z M 9.1 34.401 L 17.2 34.401 A 27.803 27.803 0 0 0 21.151 34.14 Q 23.178 33.848 24.8 33.23 A 10.46 10.46 0 0 0 28.3 31.101 A 10.525 10.525 0 0 0 31.154 26.328 Q 31.8 24.151 31.8 21.401 A 19.246 19.246 0 0 0 31.458 17.651 Q 31.023 15.465 30.036 13.784 A 9.824 9.824 0 0 0 28.3 11.601 Q 25.761 9.207 21.066 8.55 A 27.955 27.955 0 0 0 17.2 8.301 L 9.1 8.301 L 9.1 34.401 Z"
          />
        
          
        </g>
      </svg>
```

**How it looks now:**

[image]

**Question**:

How can I align the outer element so that it covers the VR properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either have to redraw the SVG itself or reposition and resize the paths using CSS.

Here I've used [an online editor](https://editor.method.ac) to load your path, edit it and export it.

```css
html, body {
    background: #000;
}
path {
    stroke: #f00;
}
```

```html
<svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="-4 -4 120 150">
        <title>Loader Logo</title>
        <g>
          <path
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="5"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="m50,5l-39,22l0,45l39,23l39,-22l0,-45l-39,-23z"
          />
          <path
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="5"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="m43.56731,31.44373l5.61742,0l-12.85636,38.55627l-6.08071,0l-12.85636,-38.55627l5.67533,0l10.25034,32.11186l10.25034,-32.11186z"
          />
           <path
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="5"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="m55.03379,70.00055l0,-38.55627l10.42407,0a20.68368,19.67251 0 0 1 3.96289,0.33874q2.29445,0.42632 4.08682,1.38913a10.94238,10.40744 0 0 1 1.88212,1.27401q3.39477,2.86088 3.55345,8.24939a20.07503,19.09361 0 0 1 0.00811,0.53593q0,3.30482 -1.65048,5.97622q-1.65048,2.6714 -4.60397,4.21365l8.10761,16.57919l-6.25444,0l-7.23894,-15.09202q-0.92658,0.11016 -1.91108,0.11016l-5.09621,0l0,14.98186l-5.26995,0zm5.26995,-19.60862l4.69083,0a16.10114,15.314 0 0 0 2.28808,-0.14376q1.17387,-0.16083 2.11319,-0.50123a6.05755,5.76141 0 0 0 2.0269,-1.17266a6.09519,5.79721 0 0 0 1.65279,-2.62899q0.37411,-1.1991 0.37411,-2.71381a11.14565,10.60077 0 0 0 -0.19806,-2.06551q-0.25192,-1.20406 -0.8235,-2.12996a5.68923,5.4111 0 0 0 -1.00534,-1.2024q-1.47037,-1.31862 -4.18932,-1.6805a16.18917,15.39772 0 0 0 -2.23886,-0.13715l-4.69083,0l0,14.37598z"
          />
        
          
        </g>
      </svg>
```

...and here is an example using your original SVG but with modified `transform` attributes:

```css
html, body {
    background: #000;
}
path {
    stroke: #f00;
}
```

```html
<svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="-4 -4 120 150">
        <title>Loader Logo</title>
        <g>
          <path
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="5"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="M 50, 5
                      L 11, 27
                      L 11, 72
                      L 50, 95
                      L 89, 73
                      L 89, 28 z"
          />
          <path
            transform="translate(18 30) scale(.60)" 
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="5"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="M 45.2 0 L 54.9 0 L 32.7 70 L 22.2 70 L 0 0 L 9.8 0 L 27.5 58.3 L 45.2 0 Z"
          />
           <path
            transform="translate(55 30) scale(.60)"
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="5"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="M 0 70.001 L 0 0.001 L 18 0.001 A 35.716 35.716 0 0 1 24.843 0.616 Q 28.805 1.39 31.9 3.138 A 18.895 18.895 0 0 1 35.15 5.451 Q 41.012 10.645 41.286 20.428 A 34.665 34.665 0 0 1 41.3 21.401 Q 41.3 27.401 38.45 32.251 Q 35.6 37.101 30.5 39.901 L 44.5 70.001 L 33.7 70.001 L 21.2 42.601 Q 19.6 42.801 17.9 42.801 L 9.1 42.801 L 9.1 70.001 L 0 70.001 Z M 9.1 34.401 L 17.2 34.401 A 27.803 27.803 0 0 0 21.151 34.14 Q 23.178 33.848 24.8 33.23 A 10.46 10.46 0 0 0 28.3 31.101 A 10.525 10.525 0 0 0 31.154 26.328 Q 31.8 24.151 31.8 21.401 A 19.246 19.246 0 0 0 31.458 17.651 Q 31.023 15.465 30.036 13.784 A 9.824 9.824 0 0 0 28.3 11.601 Q 25.761 9.207 21.066 8.55 A 27.955 27.955 0 0 0 17.2 8.301 L 9.1 8.301 L 9.1 34.401 Z"
          />
        
          
        </g>
      </svg>
```

Comment: Hey, can you help me align this SVG path? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746606/how-to-move-the-svg-path-to-the-right

Answer (score 2):

I am wrapping the paths for the VR logo in a `<symbol>` and using the symbol with `<use>`.

Please observe that the `<symbol>` has a viewBox. If a `<symbol>` has a viewBox attribute, the `<use>` element can have a width and a height. I'm using the width and the height of the  `<use>` element to resize the group. I'm using the x and y attributes to position the `<use>` element. Please observe that x="11" y="27" corresponding with the second pair of coordinates for the hexagon *d="M 50, 5 L **11, 27** L 11, 72 L 50, 95 L 89, 73 L 89, 28 z"*.

Initially viewBox="0 0 110 70" where the values used are the same as the values for x y width and height of the bounding box of the group of letters VR. Later I've changed the viewBox to viewBox="-10 -10 130 90" because I wanted a "padding" of 10 units around the group of letters.

Also please observe thet you don't need to declare the `stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"` for every path. You can declare those only once for the group.

```html
<svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="-4 -4 120 150">
<!--<symbol id="vr" viewBox="0 0 110 70">-->
    <symbol id="vr" viewBox="-10 -10 130 90">
          <path
            d="M 45.2 0 L 54.9 0 L 32.7 70 L 22.2 70 L 0 0 L 9.8 0 L 27.5 58.3 L 45.2 0 Z"
          />
           <path 
            transform="translate(65 0)"
            
            d="M 0 70.001 L 0 0.001 L 18 0.001 A 35.716 35.716 0 0 1 24.843 0.616 Q 28.805 1.39 31.9 3.138 A 18.895 18.895 0 0 1 35.15 5.451 Q 41.012 10.645 41.286 20.428 A 34.665 34.665 0 0 1 41.3 21.401 Q 41.3 27.401 38.45 32.251 Q 35.6 37.101 30.5 39.901 L 44.5 70.001 L 33.7 70.001 L 21.2 42.601 Q 19.6 42.801 17.9 42.801 L 9.1 42.801 L 9.1 70.001 L 0 70.001 Z M 9.1 34.401 L 17.2 34.401 A 27.803 27.803 0 0 0 21.151 34.14 Q 23.178 33.848 24.8 33.23 A 10.46 10.46 0 0 0 28.3 31.101 A 10.525 10.525 0 0 0 31.154 26.328 Q 31.8 24.151 31.8 21.401 A 19.246 19.246 0 0 0 31.458 17.651 Q 31.023 15.465 30.036 13.784 A 9.824 9.824 0 0 0 28.3 11.601 Q 25.761 9.207 21.066 8.55 A 27.955 27.955 0 0 0 17.2 8.301 L 9.1 8.301 L 9.1 34.401 Z"
          />
          </symbol>
        <title>Loader Logo</title>
        <g  fill="none" 
            stroke="currentColor"
            stroke-width="5"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round">
          <path id="hex"
            d="M 50, 5
                      L 11, 27
                      L 11, 72
                      L 50, 95
                      L 89, 73
                      L 89, 28 z"
          />
          
          
        <use xlink:href="#vr" x="11" y="27" width="78" height="47.5"  />
        </g>
      </svg>
```