# How to move the SVG path to the right?

Tags: svg

As seen in this image, the letter V in the hexagon is not aligned, how do I get the path that fits correctly?

Image : [image]

```
const IconLogo = () => (
  <svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" viewBox="0 0 84 96">
    <title>Logo</title>
    <g transform="translate(-8.000000, -2.000000)">
      <g transform="translate(11.000000, 5.000000)">
     
        <path
           d="M 41.406 0 L 49.805 0 A 95.806 95.806 0 0 0 48.848 2.194 A 105.56 105.56 0 0 0 48.711 2.52 Q 48.164 3.828 47.52 5.488 Q 46.918 7.038 46.197 8.997 A 303.495 303.495 0 0 0 46.094 9.277 A 187.455 187.455 0 0 0 45.48 10.976 Q 45.213 11.726 44.927 12.546 A 326.876 326.876 0 0 0 44.336 14.258 L 29.297 57.031 L 20.508 57.031 L 5.273 14.258 A 2285.455 2285.455 0 0 1 4.433 11.928 Q 4.052 10.867 3.715 9.929 A 1245.896 1245.896 0 0 1 3.496 9.316 A 389.2 389.2 0 0 0 2.812 7.419 Q 2.488 6.528 2.193 5.733 A 231.072 231.072 0 0 0 2.109 5.508 A 283.371 283.371 0 0 0 1.585 4.109 Q 1.343 3.469 1.122 2.895 A 167.042 167.042 0 0 0 0.977 2.52 A 3326.428 3326.428 0 0 1 0.237 0.612 A 2951.562 2951.562 0 0 1 0 0 L 8.398 0 L 24.883 49.414 L 41.406 0 Z"
          fill="currentColor"
        />
        <polygon
          id="Shape"
          stroke="currentColor"
          strokeWidth="8"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          points="39 0 0 22 0 67 39 90 78 68 78 23"
        />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
);

export default IconLogo;
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a transform to the first path to move it e.g.

```css
svg {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: red;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" viewBox="0 0 84 96">
    <title>Logo</title>
    <g transform="translate(-8.000000, -2.000000)">
      <g transform="translate(11.000000, 5.000000)">
        <path transform="translate(14.000000, 23.000000)"
           d="M 41.406 0 L 49.805 0 A 95.806 95.806 0 0 0 48.848 2.194 A 105.56 105.56 0 0 0 48.711 2.52 Q 48.164 3.828 47.52 5.488 Q 46.918 7.038 46.197 8.997 A 303.495 303.495 0 0 0 46.094 9.277 A 187.455 187.455 0 0 0 45.48 10.976 Q 45.213 11.726 44.927 12.546 A 326.876 326.876 0 0 0 44.336 14.258 L 29.297 57.031 L 20.508 57.031 L 5.273 14.258 A 2285.455 2285.455 0 0 1 4.433 11.928 Q 4.052 10.867 3.715 9.929 A 1245.896 1245.896 0 0 1 3.496 9.316 A 389.2 389.2 0 0 0 2.812 7.419 Q 2.488 6.528 2.193 5.733 A 231.072 231.072 0 0 0 2.109 5.508 A 283.371 283.371 0 0 0 1.585 4.109 Q 1.343 3.469 1.122 2.895 A 167.042 167.042 0 0 0 0.977 2.52 A 3326.428 3326.428 0 0 1 0.237 0.612 A 2951.562 2951.562 0 0 1 0 0 L 8.398 0 L 24.883 49.414 L 41.406 0 Z"
          fill="currentColor"
        />
        <polygon
          id="Shape"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          strokeWidth="8"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          points="39 0 0 22 0 67 39 90 78 68 78 23"
        />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `<path>` has a lot of superfluous `Q` and `A` stuff in it. The logo will still look the same if you remove those parts:

```css
svg {
    background-color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color: red;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<svg id="logo" viewBox="-3 -5 84 100">
    <title>Logo</title>
    <path transform="translate(14,22)"
           d="M 41.406 0 L 49.805 0 29.297 57.031 20.508 57.031 
              5.273 14.258 0,0 8.398 0 24.883 49.414 41.406 0 Z"
          fill="currentColor" />
    <polygon
          id="Shape"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          strokeWidth="8"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          points="39 0 0 22 0 67 39 90 78 68 78 23" />
</svg>
```

Looking at this problem for longer made me realize that it can be simplified even further by making the path *relative*. This can be achieved by applying the following `mkrel()` function to the `d` attribute of the path:

```
// this is a rudimentary version of the function:
// all coordinates in p always need to be specified in pairs!
function mkrel(p){ let x=0,y=0;
  return p.replace(/(\d+\.?\d*)[ ,\n]+(\d+\.?\d*)/g,(_,a,b)=>{
    let dx=+a-x, dy=+b-y;  // calculate relative coordinates
    x+=dx; y+=dy           // keep track of absolute coordinates
    return dx.toFixed(3)+","+dy.toFixed(3)
  });
}
```

After doing that we end up with `d` looking like this:

```
"M 41.406 0 L 8.399,0.000 -20.508,57.031 -8.789,0.000 
  -20.508,-57.031 8.398,0.000 16.485,49.414 16.523,-49.414 Z"
```

Obviously, we still need to replace the capital letters `M` and `L` by their relative counterparts `m` and `l` (the latter can even be left out!). And, after adding the transformation values of `(14,22)` to the first `m` coordinates and removing the `transform` attribute altogether we end up with a rather shorter representation of the same logo:

```css
svg {
    background-color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="logo" viewBox="-5 -5 84 100">
    <title>Logo</title>
    <path  d="m 55.406,22.000 8.399,0.000 -20.508,57.031 -8.789,0.000 
              -20.508,-57.031 8.398,0.000 16.485,49.414 16.523,-49.414 z"
           fill="currentColor"/>
    <polygon style="fill:none; stroke:currentColor; stroke-width:8px;
                    stroke-linecap:round; stroke-linejoin:round;"
           points="39 0 0 23 0 67 39 90 78 67 78 23" />
</svg>
```

The "V"-shaped inner portion of the logo can now most easily be repositioned by simply changing its initial coordinate values (`55.406,22.000`). The rest of the "V" will follow, as it is now declared *relative* to this starting coordinate.

Comment: You can paste d-paths in https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ and do all types of transformations; including relative/absolute conversion, AND rounding to get rid of the 3 digit precision still in your path. the ``d`` path then becomes: ``M55 22l8 0l-21 57l-9 0l-21-57l8 0l16 49l17-49z``